# Scanning system call table using GDB

Tags: memory, operating-system, gdb, linux-kernel, kernel

I tried scanning system call table to print the system call addresses

```
$ sudo gdb /usr/src/linux-2.6.38.8/vmlinux /proc/kcore
(gdb) x/255x 0xc12ab280 
0xc12ab280: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab290: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab2a0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab2b0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab2c0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab2d0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab2e0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab2f0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab300: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab310: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab320: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab330: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab340: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab350: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab360: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab370: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab380: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab390: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab3a0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab3b0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab3c0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab3d0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xc12ab3e0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
```

I dont understand why its printing `0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure where you got that address from but this:

```
x/255x (unsigned long*) sys_call_table
```

works fine on my linux.